How to switch between multiple videos as webcam mock in Playwright tests?
I'm working on a test automation project using Playwright where I need to simulate reading QR codes from the webcam. The test scenario involves reading QR codes from different video files. I'm trying to find a way to switch between multiple video files as the webcam mock within a single test, so that I can test different QR codes without having to manually change the video file or restart the test.
Here's a simplified version of my test code:
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';
import { getFakeVideoOptions } from './utils';

test.use({ storageState: './auth.json' });
test.use({
  ...getFakeVideoOptions('/path/to/video1.mjpeg'),
});

test.describe('Test Suite', () => {
  test.describe('Test Scenario', () => {
    test('Normal Case', async ({ page, context }) => {
      await page.goto('https://example.com');

      context.grantPermissions(['camera']);
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Button 1' }).click();
      
      // Expect to read QR code from video1
      await expect(page.getByText('Message 1')).toBeVisible();
      
      // Click a button to proceed
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Button 2' }).click();

      // Now I want to switch to video2 for the next QR code reading
      // How can I achieve this?
      
      // Expect to read QR code from video2
      await expect(page.getByText('Message 2')).toBeVisible();
    });
  });
});

The getFakeVideoOptions function is defined as follows:
export const getFakeVideoOptions = (filePath: string) =\> {
  return {
    args: \[
      '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
      '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
      `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=${filePath}`,
    \],
  };
};

In this test, I start by using video1.mjpeg as the mocked webcam input. After clicking a button and proceeding to the next step, I want to switch to video2.mjpeg for the subsequent QR code reading.
I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically change the video file used as the webcam mock within the same test.
Is there a way to achieve this in Playwright? Can I switch between different video files as the webcam mock at runtime within a single test?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
